# How can I find intersection between column and row constraints?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am a newbie for using matrix in python. I was wondering to ask you about matrix.

Input:

```
import numpy as np

wow = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0*,0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

From above matrix, I want to insert 1 in the `column` that has `all zeros` and the `row` that `sum row` equal `1` such as the intersection between column 11 and row 2. However, we need to check some approval condition through `pop` matrix before changing that intersection from 0 to 1. If the same position of intersection (`*`) in `pop` matrix is equal to 1, then we approve the intersection in `wow` matrix. If the same position of intersection (`*`) is equal to 0, no change in that intersection in `wow` matrix.

Approval condition matrix:

```
pop = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1*,0],
                [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Output: Approve the intersection to change from 0 to 1

```
>>> change_element_in(wow)
>>> wow
[[1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1* 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]]
```

Do you have a clue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to change only the one number at once and it could be any that fits the conditions. So, I suggest the following algorithm:

First, get the necessary imports:

```py
import numpy as np
# Import NDArray to get the type hints in our functions 
# and to make autocomplete work in IDEs
from numpy.typing import NDArray
```

Then create a function for finding suitable rows:

```py
def find_rows(matrix: NDArray):
    rows = []
    # matrix.sum return the list of sums of the elements along each axis
    row_sums = matrix.sum(axis=1)
    # Go through all row sums to find suitable rows
    for row_index, row_sum in enumerate(row_sums):
        if row_sum == 1:
            rows.append(row_index)
    return rows
```

Similarly, find the suitable columns as well:

```py
def find_columns(matrix: NDArray):
    columns = []
    # Transpose the matrix to inspect through columns
    transposed = matrix.transpose()
    # Check if there is non-zero element for each column
    zero_checks = transposed.any(axis=1)
    # Go through all row sums to find suitable columns
    for column_index, column_check in enumerate(zero_checks):
        if not column_check:
            columns.append(column_index)
    return columns
```

Now, we can implement function for inserting the one into our matrix:

```py
def insert_one(matrix: NDArray, approval_matrix: NDArray):
    # Get the suitable rows and columns for matrix
    possible_rows = find_rows(matrix)
    possible_columns = find_columns(matrix)
    # List comprehension to create a list of all possible cells
    possible_cells = [(row, column) for row in possible_rows
                                    for column in possible_columns]
    for cell in possible_cells:
        # Check if the corresponding element is 1 in the approval matrix
        if approval_matrix[cell] == 1:
            matrix[cell] = 1
            # If some element in the matrix is changed, return 0
            return 0
    # If nothing is changed in the matrix, return 1
    return 1
```

For the matrices you provided I got the following result:

```py
wow = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
])
pop = np.array([
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
])
insert_one(matrix=wow, approval_matrix=pop)
print(wow)
```

Output (I mark with `*` the modified element):

```
[[1 0 0  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1* 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]]
```

If you need to change your matrix this way multiple times, just execute `insert_one` function in the `while` loop keeping track at its return value. When it returns `1` there is nothing to change there.